# Перехват JS функций в IOS

Tags: cocoa, ios

Добрый день!

Есть такой вопрос:
Мы имеем UIViewController на котором расположен UIWebView, в процессе работы апа в UIWebView подгружается сайт в котором есть ссылка

```
<a href="" onclick="mobile_app.performClick()">Проверить</a>
```

Так вот, при нажатии на эту ссылку в мобильном браузере необходимо выполнить некий код в классах приложения. В Android версии это делается так -

```
w.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
{
   @SuppressWarnings("unused")
   public void performClick()
   {
      startScanActivity();
   }
},
```

где  w = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);

Т.Е. мы перехватываем JS событие onClick и если оно равно performClick то выполняем функции приложения.

Задача: повторить это же на IOS

Надеюсь на вашу помощь! Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Возможно есть и другие способы, но я использовал только один - послать реквест куда-нибудь из js и перехватить его в `UIWebViewDelegate в - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*) webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *) request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType) navigationType` , пара ссылок по теме:

- [Send a BOOL value from JavaScript to Objective-C](http://www.chucksmith.de/2009/04/send-bool-value-from-javascript-to-objective-c/)
- [Basic Multiple Window Support for iOS UIWebView](http://www.hesslerdesign.com/blog/ios/basic-multi-window-support-for-ios-uiwebview/)

Comment: Находилось подобноее решение - http://www.imaladec.com/story/objective_c_and_javascript, однако оно не совсем мне подошло. Дело в том что IOS требует писать функцию релокации

function ObjCAlert() {
   document.location = "jsexample:alert:iMaladec_alert_from_JS";
};

а эта функция - релоадит страницу и тогда только ее хватает IOS
а вот Android - этот релоад совершенно не нужен.

Comment: тогда не знаю, если только выполнять разный код в зависимости от оси хоста

Comment: Спасибо! Вообщем то так и сделали, от оси хоста и все. :)